# How to access individual trees in a model created by RandomForestClassifier (spark.ml-version)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

How to access individual trees in a model generated by Spark ML's [RandomForestClassifier](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier)? I am using the Scala version of RandomForestClassifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it has `trees` attribute:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.NominalAttribute
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.{
  RandomForestClassificationModel, RandomForestClassifier, 
  DecisionTreeClassificationModel
}

val meta = NominalAttribute
  .defaultAttr
  .withName("label")
  .withValues("0.0", "1.0")
  .toMetadata

val data = sqlContext.read.format("libsvm")
  .load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")
  .withColumn("label", $"label".as("label", meta))

val rf: RandomForestClassifier = new RandomForestClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")

val trees: Array[DecisionTreeClassificationModel] = rf.fit(data).trees.collect {
  case t: DecisionTreeClassificationModel => t
}
```

As you can see the only problem is to get types right so we can actually use these:

```
trees.head.transform(data).show(3)
// +-----+--------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
// |label|            features|rawPrediction|probability|prediction|
// +-----+--------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
// |  0.0|(692,[127,128,129...|   [33.0,0.0]|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|
// |  1.0|(692,[158,159,160...|   [0.0,59.0]|  [0.0,1.0]|       1.0|
// |  1.0|(692,[124,125,126...|   [0.0,59.0]|  [0.0,1.0]|       1.0|
// +-----+--------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
// only showing top 3 rows
```

**Note**:

If you work with pipelines you can extract individual trees as well:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

val model = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(rf)).fit(data)

// There is only one stage and know its type 
// but lets be thorough
val rfModelOption = model.stages.headOption match {
  case Some(m: RandomForestClassificationModel) => Some(m)
  case _ => None
}

val trees = rfModelOption.map {
  _.trees //  ... as before
}.getOrElse(Array())
```

Comment: Hi zero323, thanks for your help. I have a follow up question. I want to extract rules from tree nodes with high prediction probabilities (say above 0.3). In `spark.ml`, the object impurityStats is private in an internal node of the tree and so are methods toOld and fromOld. I need those details (which I can't access as they are private) to be able to extract anything. Similarly the split of the node doesn't provide any info on its categories and feature thresholds. Is there any way to extract rules from high probability nodes in `spark.ml`?

Comment: I am not aware of any trivial solution.  You should ask it as a separate - maybe somebody has already a solution in place. If you do please ping me with a link.

Comment: Thanks zero323. I just posted the question "How to extract rules from Spark ML RandomForestClassifier model (Scala version)?". Will keep you updated if I get an answer.